# Does socket.io emit a lot of processing power?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I have a socket.io client which needs to listen if a specific user logs in/out to my socket.io server
what I did is create a function which takes an array of userID, and a callback which return the user information if he logged in/out. here's the code:

```
        this.onUserConnected = function(arrayOfUserID,cb){

            if(typeof arrayOfUserID != 'object'){
                return console.error('1st parameter is not an array');
            }
            socket.on('onUserConnected', function(user) {
              if(arrayOfUserID.indexOf(user.user_id) > -1){
                    cb(user)
                }
            })
        }

        this.onUserDisconnected = function(arrayOfUserID,cb){
            if(typeof arrayOfUserID != 'object'){
                return console.error('onUserDisconnected 1st parameter is not an array');
            }
            socket.on('onUserDisconnected', function(user) {
                if(arrayOfUserID.indexOf(user.user_id) > -1){
                    cb(user)
                }
            })
        }
```

Here is the socket.io server code:

```
 //Some authentication here which check and get the user if he exists
 socket.emit('onUserConnected', user)
```

Is it good that I emit the user to all connected socket? and in the client-side, is it good that I fetch all the user who logged in/out and just check the user_id if it is equal to one of the value in the arrayOfUserID then return it?

Note: I know Socket.io Rooms, but in my application I handle multiple tabs, and I have a dynamic namespace

Comment: Do you only call `this.onUserConnected()` once or do you call it multiple times with different arguments?

Comment: @jfriend00 just once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does socket.io emit a lot of processing power?

It's not clear exactly what you mean here.  socket.io, by itself, just uses TCP to send webSocket messages.  It does not use a lot of processing power, though if you are sending a lot of messages to a lot of clients, that can use some CPU.

> Is it good that I emit the user to all connected socket?

In general, you should only send clients information that they actually need.  Sending all clients all information about all clients will limit your scalability as there could be lots and lots of updates going to all clients.  Every transmission received by a client also consumes some power (relevant for battery powered devices) so limiting the transmissions is good for clients too.

The most efficient scheme would usually be to have the client tell the server exactly what information it wants and have the server send only that info to the client and send it only when it changes.  This would be more efficient than having the server sending all info to the client and letting the client sort through it.

> and in the client-side, is it good that I fetch all the user who
>   logged in/out and just check the user_id if it is equal to one of the
>   value in the arrayOfUserID then return it?

Same answer as above.  If you can have the server alert the client only when something it is interested has happened, that is usually better.

> Note: I know Socket.io Rooms, but in my application I handle multiple
>   tabs, and I have a dynamic namespace

You can use socket.io rooms just fine for dynamically created rooms.  You haven't described your actual application, but rooms are an excellent built-in way for groups of users to communicate or update each other and it's easy for the server to manage this communication using the built-in features of rooms.